# declare: "additional attributes do not take effect until subsequent assignments"

Tags: bash

From Bash manual for `declare` command:

> When using `-a` or `-A` and the compound assignment syntax to create array
>   variables, additional attributes do not take effect until subsequent assignments.

What does it mean?

I can't figure it out by

```
$ declare -ar arr=([1]=2, [2]=3)
$ declare -p arr
declare -ar arr='([1]="2," [2]="3")'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What it says is that attributes other than `-a` and `-A` won't have any effect during the first assignment.

Example with the uppercase attribute:

```
$ declare -a -u array=( hello )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
hello
$ array+=( world )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
hello
WORLD
```

Comment: However, the documentation is incomplete in that it doesn't apply to `-x` or `-r`. Why it's that way is also not clear to me. That may be just to document a known limitation, but I can't imagine it being very hard to fix.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You mean that `-x` has an immediate effect, right? I concur. OTOH, I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't apply to `-r`". `-r` has no effect during the first assignment, for all variable types.

Comment: I mean it doesn't need another assignment to make the variable read-only. It's already read-only by the time typeset returns (as in the attribute takes effect straight away). That's the case mentioned by the OP.